# is adding metatags dynamically in code behind useful for SEO or not ?

Tags: asp.net, seo

Dears , i was reading this post about adding the meta tags dynamically by code in asp.net 4 - but i need to ask what is the good for SEO , adding it static or no problem with adding it in code behind

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/05/asp-net-4-seo-improvements-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SEO aspect is simply that of *having* meta tags that accurately represent the page. The search engines have no way of telling if they were added statically or dynamically and don't really care about that aspect.

The addition of the `MetaKeywords` and `MetaDescription` to the Page class is to simplify dynamic creation of these meta tags - for example if these come from a database, with the rest of the page content.

In earlier versions, one was forced to create literal controls or other ways to generate dynamic meta tags.

Answer (score 0):

Generally `MetaKeywords` is a waste of time from an SEO point of view, since most major search engines ignore them, [including Google](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=79812) (due to over abuse). However, `MetaDescription` is a useful one and should be completed if you can generate a meaningful summary of that accurately describes the page's contents. For more info on what Meta tags Google supports [check here](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=79812).

Generating Meta tags in code behind is useful for sites that have dynamic content drawn into them, such as occurs in a CMS or other data-driven websites. You just have to ensure that what you generate is accurate and useful for the site. This also goes for other things like the browser TITLE tag and things like H1 and H2 tags, which are all important from an SEO point of view.

Answer (score 0):

This is something I found on seotoolscentral.com. It worked in a considerable manner for my site.  I added different meta tags for different pages in same site like http://www.mysite.com/web/home/index.php, http://www.mysite.com/web/automobile/

I thinks the below explanations will help

> The Meta Description Tag doesn't affect your page's ranking in the
>   search engines (for the most part), but it is still important for your
>   SEO. Google may choose to display meta descriptions in the search
>   results, which will help users to have a clear idea of the URL's
>   content. It is worth having an accurate meta description, which may
>   improve your Click-through. Try to limit its length to 60 - 150
>   characters.
>
> Although the keyword meta tags don't count in Google's ranking, it is
>   still a major factor for other search engines to consider. Ideally,
>   your meta keywords should contain no more than 256 characters, and
>   separate the words or phrases using a comma.